# Visual Studio 2019 breakpoint in default.cshtml will break on every default.cshtml

Tags: razor, breakpoints

I have a project with several default.cshtml files, if I set a breakpoint on one of them Visual Studio 2019 will break on every one of them. Does anyone know how to avoid this ?

Comment: I don't really understand. Does it break on everyone of them at the same time or one after the other? OR does it break on your desired one first and somehow navigates to the others?

Comment: It breaks on one after the other. I have a project with multiple default.cshtml files which are different and I want to debug one of them so I set a breakpoint in it. After that, starting a debug session hits one after another. You can try yourself, the project I am working on is nopCommerce version 4.10 : https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/releases/